# Why does Ginger use DEA as her cover in Swordfish?

Tags: plot-explanation, swordfish

For a movie about hacking, technology, terrorism and patriotism, why in the world does Ginger use DEA as her cover when talking to Stan?

DEA - Drug Enforcement Agency. The movie never once mentions drugs. While I understand that Stan has no knowledge of Gabriel, the story could hold up but Stan comes to learn all about Gabriel and his plans which don't include drugs. Plus, when Stan first meets Gabriel in the club, he wants him to hack into the DoD (department of defense).

At the end when Gabriel shoots Ginger, he tells Stan, "She was DEA".

Was this explained somewhere in maybe a directors cut or a book? Homeland security, FBI, CIA, ATF - those all make more sense. So why DEA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The money they are stealing is the DEA's. From [IMDb's summary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0244244/plotsummary):

> When the **DEA** shut down its dummy corporation **operation codenamed SWORDFISH** in 1986, they had generated $400 million which they let sit around; fifteen years of compound interest has swelled it to $9.5 billion. A covert counter-terrorist unit called Black Cell, headed by the duplicitious and suave Gabriel Shear, wants the money to help finance their raise-the-stakes vengeance war against international terrorism, but it's all locked away behind super-encryption. He brings in convicted hacker Stanley Jobson, who only wants to see his daughter Holly again but can't afford the legal fees, to slice into the government mainframes and get the money.

Comment: Now it makes perfect sense! Can't believe I didn't catch that.

Comment: "super-encryption" almost makes me cringe as much as the "hacking" used in the film