# Why is Ginger wearing a wire in Swordfish?

Tags: swordfish

This is a follow up question to [Why does Ginger use DEA as her cover in Swordfish?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/why-does-ginger-use-dea-as-her-cover-in-swordfish)

Why is Ginger wearing a wire when Stan walks in on her getting dressed? The scene is played out to where it doesn't look like it was to setup Stan and get him to participate by feeding him the DEA story.

But, because I missed the DEA story in my previous question, I may be missing something here as well.

So, why is Ginger wearing a wire?

Comment: I imagine it really was just to convince Stan she was a DEA agent.

Comment: That's what I think as well, BUT, Stan had just come back and went looking for her. As far as I know, it doesn't explain her setting it up. Unless you take the fact that she joins Gabriel on the boat in the end as proof, but that makes it seem far fetched. Maybe it was just to keep the audience in suspense because Gabriel is one of those bad guys who you want to win. So it was placed there not for Stan, but for us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undercover DEA agents will certainly not bother locking the door whilst undressing, right? :) Of course it was planned and was a push to convince Stanley Jobson to give Gabriel the "worm" and not derail the plan in any way.

[image: Ginger Knowles wearing the wire.]

> **Ginger** *(while undressed)*: But it's not you we're after. It's Gabriel. So just give him the worm, take the money, and get the hell out of here. That's all you gotta do.

There really was no way for Gabriel to verify that the worm was actually genuine as he would have needed another hacker of Stan's calibre to do so. Ginger's wire play was therefore a psychological ploy to improve the odds in his favour.

<sup><sub>You ought to watch the [alternate endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swordfish_%28film%29#Alternate_endings) on the DVD.</sub></sup>

Comment: I do agree with you, but I'm looking for anything that can provide proof that it was meant to help convince him to do what he was paid to do. But, I don't think there is proof. I think it was meant for both Stan and the audience. So I accept your answer.

Comment: @DustinDavis Isn't the proof that she wasn't DEA sufficient?

Comment: that's what sparked my question to begin with :) I'm accepting your answer that it was to make the story believable to stan in an attempt to get him to do what they wanted. It probably back fired though and made stan think he could help the DEA by screwing Gabriel. With my assumption that it wasn't explicitly explained because it was meant for the audience, your answer makes even more sense and I accept that.